# Yum Install Issue in Centos while installing Couchbase

Tags: centos, yum

I was trying to run the below command to install packages in Centos.

**[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo yum install -y pkgconfig**
After running the above command getting the below error.

`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ee.repo, line: 1
'<!doctype html>\n'`

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Couchbase at all. Looks like your `/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ee.repo` is not really plain text, and has HTML content instead. Try to remove this file and retry.